# Upgrading to Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

I have an Acer laptop with Windows Vista Home Premium.  How do I upgrade to Windows 7 Professional?  And what is Windows 7 Prfessional N?

Answer (score 1):

According to the table below, you need a custom (clean) installation. I recommend you to run [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displaylang=en).

> Download and run the Windows 7 Upgrade
>   Advisor to see if your PC is ready for
>   Windows 7. It scans your hardware,
>   devices, and installed programs for
>   known compatibility issues, gives you
>   guidance on how to resolve potential
>   issues found, and recommends what to
>   do before you upgrade.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not recommend upgrading, a fresh install would be a much cleaner alternative.  Backup your data and do a fresh install.  You will thank me after you upgrade, run into problems and then do a clean install.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its a European version due to Europe's laws

http://crave.cnet.co.uk/software/windows-7-n-the-n-editions-explained-49303415/

It all started with XP
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886540